# letsencrypt and DNS A record for subdomains

Tags: nginx, dns

I have a website behind a firewall lets call it
www.mysite.mycompany.com
I want to enable SSL on the server serving this website.

I am reading this article 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7
And that article mentions 
A DNS A Record that points your domain to the public IP address of your server...

I don't have control over the corporate DNS but since my site is a subdomain of mycompany.com do i still
need to make that DNS A record ?

Comment: If your website is reachable from the public internet, then this record already exists.

Comment: No my site is not reachable from the public internet